# How prevent operation run until it complete

Tags: c#, operation

We have food register system that work with mudbus protocol over serial port. users register food via RFID card on device
this system work with polling and poll every device and request record from it, if device has record send it and software after control some validations, return response to it, this operation can take long time ( 1 to 2 second) but we don't wait for response and put this operation on another thread, every time response ready, we send it to device, but during response prepare we continue polling other device but i write code that device has incomplete operation not polled.
current system work correctly but a problem occurred after one week.for some users 2 food registered. that means same record read from device several time.
(only one operation run in time. operations picked up from queue)

```
   public abstract class Operation
   {
        public OperationResult Run(IDevice currentDevice)
        {
            OperationResult result = new OperationResult();
            try
            {

            lock (_activeOpLock)
            {
                if (IsSingleTransaction)
                {
                    var opHashCode = GetHashCode();
                    var oldOp =  ActiveOperations.FirstOrDefault( x => x.DeviceCode == currentDevice.Code && x.OperationCode == opHashCode);

                    //here i return, because operation not completed yet and don't allow same record read from device .
                    //but this code not run correctly.
                    if (oldOp != null)
                        return new OperationResult()
                        {
                            Result = OperationResultType.SingleTransactionError,
                            Message = "This Operatin set to Single Transaction and Another operation use device, and must complete."
                        };

                    //if operation not running i add it to list and remove it when completed.
                    ActiveOperations.Add(new ActiveOperation()
                    {
                        DeviceCode = currentDevice.Code,
                        OperationCode = opHashCode
                    });
                }

            }
            //here the drived class connect to device and send command to it.
           //this class has RunAsync method and allow drived class run 
          //response preparation on another thread and this class 
         //can  check status of it with _isRunningAsync variable.

            result = RunAction(currentDevice);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           .....
        }
        finally
        {

            if (IsSingleTransaction)
            {
                if (!_isRunningAsync)
                {
                    RemoveActiveOperation(GetHashCode(), currentDevice.Code);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void RemoveActiveOperation(int opCode, int deviceCode)
    {
        lock (_activeOpLock)
        {
            var op = ActiveOperations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OperationCode == opCode && x.DeviceCode == deviceCode);
            if (op != null)
                ActiveOperations.Remove(op);
        }
    }

    protected virtual async void RunAsync(Func<OperationResponse> task, Device currentDevice)
    {
            ...........
            if (IsSingleTransaction && currentDevice != null)
            {
                RemoveActiveOperation(GetHashCode(), currentDevice.Code);
            }
    }
```

}

i use this class in blow code;

```
public void RunOperation(Operation op)
{
    foreach(var device in ActiveDevices)
    {           
        //my problem is here, how skip device that not completed operation.
        //i think my design is not correct , but currently i can't change my design.
        op.Run(device);
    }
}
```

Comment: is my implementation wrong?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand or read full code. Edit your post, show where you are having problem.

Comment: If there's a code region you want to run asynchronously while only allowing a single caller to execute that region at any given time, use `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` to protect that region